# String in android with input value

Tags: java

i am new in android, how can i make a string function, with input and return?

something like this :

```
public String (String Input)
{
    String a = "a";
    a += Input;
    return a;
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like that.
No, seriously, just like you did above, but you need to add a name for your method:

```
public String MethodName (String Input)
{
    String a = "a";
    a += Input;
    return a;
}
```

Then you can call your method like:

```
String sample = MethodName("input");
```

Comment: @PsylentStriker, I edited my answer if you want to know how to call your 'String' method

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Android in any way.

In Java this is how you declare a method:

```
<visibility> <some identifiers like static, final> <return type> <name>(<arguments>)
{
     <body>
}
```

> If the return type is void you can avoid the return. If it's something else you should always return something from the function using `return`

So your code here miss

```
public String (String Input)
{
    String a = "a";
    a += Input;
    return a;
}
```

This method takes a `String` `input` and returns the merge with `a` and the string passed when the method is called.

Example:

```
<functionName>("Hello");
```

the output will be `aHello`

Example:

```
public String test(String Input)
{
    String a = "a";
    a += Input;
    return a;
}

String output = test("World");
```

the `output` variable will be `aWorld`